# Learning Eclipse Visual Editor Swing with Java

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, swing, visual-editor

I am trying to create a java GUI project for school using Eclipse Visual Editor with Swing. But i am having a lot of issues learning this since this is the first time i am making a GUI.

Like when i drag JPanel into my screen, it creates a function for it, but how do i call it in a separate file?

I guess my question is does anyone know of any good resources that can help me learn how to use visual editor (links, books, youtube videos, examples)?

Thanks =]

Comment: The VE in Eclipse totally sucks. If you want to use a GUI designer with Swing - better take a look at NetBeans...

Comment: All Swing development I have seen is typically done by hand. Isolate your pieces into smaller panels and simply glue those panels together.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of tutorials for using the Visual Editor.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecvisual/
and
http://www.cs.siu.edu/~wainer/484S05/visEdit/eclipseVE.pdf

Here is the [Swing Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/)

Comment: @bat if I answered your question, then please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are learning to create swing application and you need a visual editor for that; then I suppose you should be using NetBeans IDE.

http://netbeans.org/

Answer (score 0):

Or Google Toolkit belt, with  window builder in Eclipse ;)